# Definitions of non degenerate bilinear forms

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, dual-spaces, bilinear-form

Referring to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_bilinear_form) Wikipedia page, The definition of a *non degenerate* bilinear form
is given as a bilinear form $f(x,y)$ such that $v \to (x \to f(x,v))$ is an isomorphism.
We are also told that the below construct is an equivalent definition,
when $V$ is finite dimentional:

$$
f(x,y) = 0 \hspace{2ex} \forall\ y \in V \hspace{2ex} \text{implies}\hspace{2ex} x = 0
$$

In other words the kernel of the mapping $\ \psi:V \to V^{*}$ defined by $\ \psi := v \to
(x \to f(x,v))$ is trivial, that is $\operatorname{Ker}(\psi) = \{0\}$.

---

My question is how do we prove that the two definitions are equivalent? How does the latter
formulation show that $\psi$ is isomorphic?

Comment: Your link says that these are equivalent notions when $V$ is finite-dimensional. When $V$ is finite-dimensional, then $\dim V^* = \dim V$, and so $\ker\psi = \{0\}$ is equivalent to saying $\psi$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: @TedShifrin Ohh Yes, I forgot to include that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $x\mapsto (y\mapsto f(x,y))$ is an isomorphism. Then it has trivial kernel, meaning $\psi(x)=0$ implies $x=0$. This is equivalent to the statement $f(x,y)=0$ for all $y$ implies $x=0$.

For the converse statement (assuming we are on a finite vectorspace), simply use the fact, that being an isomorphism between two vectorspaces of the same dimension is equivalent to having a trivial kernel.

Comment: okay the original wiki page gives $\psi$ as $y \to (x \to f(x,y))$, but the condition as $f(x,y)=0\ \forall\ y \implies\ x = 0$ which confused me. It is also worth mentioning that the page lacks sources.

Comment: You can prove that this is actually equivalent. If you have learned about the associated matrix to the bilinearform, then you just need to see that nondegeneracy is equivalent to that matrix having non zero determinant. Changing $x$ and $y$ in the definition of Wikipedia gives the transpose matrix, which has the same determinant.